# Varnish 3.0 returns 503 error

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using varnish to cache the content of my websites. It is working as it supposed, but there is a problem. Randomly it returns an 503 error, it is really strange, since the app servers are ok and the load is under .8, also the database server its ok. Here is part of my configuration:

```
backend app05 {
  .host = "app05.site.com";
  .port = "80";
  .connect_timeout = 0.7s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 30s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 30s;
  .probe = {
    .url = "/";
    .interval = 5s;
    .timeout = 1s;
    .window = 5;
    .threshold = 3;
  }
}

director app_director round-robin {
  { .backend = app01; }
  { .backend = app02; }
  { .backend = app03; }
  { .backend = app04; }
  { .backend = app05; }   
}

sub vcl_fetch {

  # remove all cookies
  # unset beresp.http.set-cookie;

  # cache for 12 hours
  # set beresp.ttl = 2h;

  # Don't allow static files to set cookies.
  if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js|html|htm|mp4|flv)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 12h;
  } else {
    set beresp.ttl = 30m;
  }

  # If the backend server doesn't return properly, don't send another connection to it
  # for 60s and try another backend via restart.
  #
  # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html
  # --
  if(beresp.status == 500) {
    set beresp.saintmode = 5m;
    if (req.request != "POST") {
      return(restart);
    } else {
      error 500 "Failed";
    }
  }

  # Allow items to be stale if needed.
  set beresp.grace = 1h;

}
```

Do I have to add also to the if beresp.status == 503?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the congfig file. Have your tried checking logs with varnish_log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fix this. I only had to increase the time the connection expires and check the number of the reconnection. Here are the lines I had add:

```
host = "app01.site.com";
  .port = "80";
  .connect_timeout = 1.5s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 45s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 30s;

if (req.restarts > 3) {
  set beresp.saintmode = 5m;
}
```

Comment: Would have helped to mention in which subroutines you added the saintmode.

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi this was 6 years ago, so now I don't remember... but maybe it was under the main configuration. As you can see in the question, lines 2 to 6 matches the ones in the answer, so probably the `saintmode` was added after those lines... sorry for not having a better answer at this time :(

Comment: I think they got rid of the concept. Now setting any kind of grace automatically sends stale response and tries to fetch a new one, and if new one fails it keeps sending stale...

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi Do you have the reference? Perhaps you can edit the answer adding more information. Honestly, it has been years since I stopped working with this, so I'm really rusty on it... otherwise I'd do it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.